FPV Drone Motor Speed Behavior: Unusual Slider Response in Betaflight
I'm building an FPV drone and have encountered a strange issue when checking motor behavior in the Betaflight Configurator. When I move the slider in the "Motors" tab, one of my motors behaves unusually.
Here’s what's happening:
The motor reaches its maximum speed when the slider is halfway.
After that, the motor speed drops to zero as I continue moving the slider.
When I move the slider further, the motor speed increases again and reaches full speed when the slider is at the top position.

Essentially, for a single movement of the slider, the motor speed fluctuates twice: from low to high, and then back to low, before increasing again.
The motor is working fine, but I'm unsure whether this is an issue with the flight controller, ESC, or a Betaflight setting. I haven’t yet tested the motor with a different ESC or controller to isolate the issue.
My questions:
Are there any Betaflight settings that could cause this kind of motor behavior?
How should I go about troubleshooting to narrow down whether the issue is with the flight controller, ESC, or elsewhere?

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance!
